# Neo4J IN operator

Tags: java, neo4j

I am having trouble using the IN operator in a Cypher query, using the embedded Java API. It would appear that you are unable to utilize the IN operator with an identifier other than the entity(ies) retrieved in the `start` clause.

For example, here is my query:

```
start n=node(someLongNodeId) 
match n--m 
where m.gnid? IN [\"someStringId\",\"otherStringId\"] 
return m
```

I can utilize the IN operator when filtering on a property of `n`, but it fails with the following exception when I execute the above query and attempt to call `hasNext()` on the `Iterator` returned from `columnAs("m")`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.matching.MiniMap.newWith(ExpanderStep.scala:172)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.matching.MiniMap.newWith(ExpanderStep.scala:155)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.commands.InCollection$$anonfun$isMatch$1.apply(InCollection.scala:39)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.commands.InCollection$$anonfun$isMatch$1.apply(InCollection.scala:38)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.exists(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:79)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.exists(List.scala:45)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.commands.AnyInCollection$$anonfun$seqMethod$2.apply(InCollection.scala:71)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.commands.AnyInCollection$$anonfun$seqMethod$2.apply(InCollection.scala:71)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.commands.InCollection.isMatch(InCollection.scala:38)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.commands.And.isMatch(Predicate.scala:83)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.matching.FilteringIterable$FilteringIterator.spoolToNextInLine(FilteringIterable.scala:55)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.matching.FilteringIterable$FilteringIterator.<init>(FilteringIterable.scala:34)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.matching.FilteringIterable.iterator(FilteringIterable.scala:72)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.matching.FilteringIterable.iterator(FilteringIterable.scala:27)
    at scala.collection.JavaConversions$IterableWrapperTrait$class.iterator(JavaConversions.scala:557)
    at scala.collection.JavaConversions$IterableWrapper.iterator(JavaConversions.scala:583)
    at scala.collection.JavaConversions$IterableWrapper.iterator(JavaConversions.scala:583)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.TraversalBranchWithState.expandRelationshipsWithoutChecks(TraversalBranchWithState.java:70)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.TraversalBranchImpl.expandRelationships(TraversalBranchImpl.java:104)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.StartNodeTraversalBranch.next(StartNodeTraversalBranch.java:47)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.AsOneStartBranch.next(AsOneStartBranch.java:100)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.PreorderDepthFirstSelector.next(PreorderDepthFirstSelector.java:52)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.TraverserIterator.fetchNextOrNull(TraverserIterator.java:65)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.TraverserIterator.fetchNextOrNull(TraverserIterator.java:34)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.hasNext(PrefetchingIterator.java:55)
    at scala.collection.JavaConversions$JIteratorWrapper.hasNext(JavaConversions.scala:574)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$21.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$21.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$22.hasNext(Iterator.scala:388)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$19.hasNext(Iterator.scala:334)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$19.hasNext(Iterator.scala:334)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.PipeExecutionResult.hasNext(PipeExecutionResult.scala:138)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$19.hasNext(Iterator.scala:334)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$19.hasNext(Iterator.scala:334)
    at scala.collection.JavaConversions$IteratorWrapper.hasNext(JavaConversions.scala:562)
    at com.awesomecompany.data.neo.NeoTestDriver.performBidirectionalQuery(NeoTestDriver.java:122)
    at com.awesomecompany.data.neo.NeoTestDriver.main(NeoTestDriver.java:44)
```

Am I correct in my assumption that you cannot use the IN operator on something other than `n` in my example? Is this a bug, or is this by design?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wanted to answer my own question, in case other people are having similar issues. There are a couple things that I want to adress in reference to the above example:

Per [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/neo4j/in%2420operator/neo4j/neBGEq_WG8E/dIElWgE19kUJ) in the neo4j Google Group forum

- I added the HAS() function to the WHERE clause
- I also changed the array values to use a single quote (`'`) instead of the  previous double quotes

So my new example query looks like this:

```
start n=node(someLongNodeId) 
match n--m 
where HAS(m.gnid) AND m.gnid IN ['someStringId','otherStringId'] 
return m
```

This worked as expected.

After making the above edits, I converted my query to use parameters (which if JDBC has taught me anything, is the correct way to perform queries like this). That query looked like this:

```
start n=node({nodeId}) 
match n--m 
where HAS(m.gnid) AND m.gnid IN {otherIds}
return m
```

This also worked correctly.

The IN operator is not terribly well documented at the moment, which is understandable since it is fairly new to the neo4j project, but I wanted to make sure this was answered in case anybody else is having similar troubles.

Comment: A tiny sample database works without the `HAS()` :http://console.neo4j.org/?id=qnatzd

Comment: You are correct, but only if you use the `*` operator in your start clause. Try again with a specific node id.

Comment: Another note to make, per the forum discussion. If you wanted to do this with the neo4j-generated ids, instead of the HAS function, your where clause would need to look like this `where NOT(ID(m) IS NULL) AND ID(m) IN {ids}`

Comment: If this is Neo4j 1.8.1 then the HAS is just a workaround- it's a known issue https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/390

Comment: should be solved in the next milestone, it was an issue and the has() is a workaround. it only occurs when you have a `MATCH` and `IN` in your query, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I'll update the question with a note to this effect when the update is released. Thanks for the info. So far, except for a couple hiccups here and there, I love your product and can't wait to see where it will go.